# Laravel Password Basic Hashing

Tags: laravel, hash, crypt

I want to encrypt password in Laravel.But Hash or Crypt are encryting again again every page refresh. So I dont use it.

```
  $pass = Hash::make($user_password);
  $pass = Crypt::encrypt($user_password);
```

How can i do one times encrypt with Hash or Crypt method ? Because I can't do login page with Hash.

**I solved this problem**

```
  public function login(Request $request)
    {
    
     $email = $request->input('user_email');
     $password = $request->input('user_password');

     $user = BO_USER::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
     if (!$user) {
        return response()->json(['success'=>false, 'message' => 'Login Fail, please check email id']);
     }
     if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {
        return response()->json(['success'=>false, 'message' => 'Login Fail, pls check password']);
     }
        //return response()->json(['success'=>true,'message'=>'success', 'data' => $user]);
       return redirect('/dashboard');
    }
```

Comment: Don't bother with `Crypt` (can be decrypted) for passwords, you want to use `Hash` (one-way). Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're saying... Typical approach, Hash and save to DB, then compare user input with saved password. Try to explain your problem a bit better; it's a little unclear at the moment.

Comment: What do you mean it is encrypting on every page refresh? Where in your codebase have you placed the call to Hash? 

At the highest level, what are you wanting to do? If you want a login system for laravel, have you ruled out breeze, jetstream, and fortify?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to remove the solution and post your solution as an answer to this post. You can self-answer, but you should only do that as a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

You will use the `Hash`, cause `Crypt` can be decrypted.

See documentation:

- [Hashing for password](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/hashing#hashing-passwords)
- [Encrypt and decrypt values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption#encrypting-a-value)